# How can I get SQL Server Analysis Services to forecast a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cluster-analysis, forecasting

I have a table with all my customers and a set of variable related to them, for some of them I have their "net income" and for some of them I don't. What I want is to forecast (guess) what would be the "net income" for those clients which I don't have it based on the other variables I already have.

I am using SQL Serve Analysis Services - Clustering Tool, but I haven't been able to get what I need. I just get the clusters but I don't have their "net income".

How can I configure SQL Server Analysis Services for it instead of giving me a set of clusters, give a me a set of cluster BUT with their estimated "net income"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered **computing the average "net income"** of each cluster *yourself*? Should be a simple SQL query along the lines of `SELECT AVG(net_income) FROM table GROUP BY clusterid` (+ the appropriate join with the clustering result).

In practise, you may want to use a more complex regression model than taking the average, though.